# Can't connect to MySQL server on

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm getting this error on my server:

```
Can't connect to MySQL server on '50.57.95.218' (111) in eval() (line 12 of /var/www/public_html/modules/php/php.module(80) : eval()'d code).
```

Now, as far as I can tell, my credentials are correct.

I've got this in PHPMyAdmin:

```
USERNAME    localhost    global  SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, SHOW VIEW
```

And this is also setup in my Drupal settings.php, however, for some reason, I'm getting this error and not being able to login into the site (the site displays perfectly though).

How do I fix this? Any ideas jump out?

Why wouldn't it be able to connect if the user credentials are correct?

Comment: what does that long string of text in phpMyAdmin have to do with you connecting to the db?

Comment: @Phil It appears to be the user's database permissions.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, it looks like your MySQL connection string may be pointing to your server's external IP address.  If the MySQL Server is on the same machine, change your host to 'localhost'.

If the server is, indeed on a separate machine, make sure that your firewall is set to allow incoming connections on port 3306 (default MySQL port) and that the user you're using to login with has the permissions to connect from a remote host.

Comment: But the permissions he posted only show access from localhost, so I think your first paragraph is probably the right answer.

Comment: I'm thinking so too, but I thought I'd add the second paragraph just in case :)

Comment: That's odd, because my Drupal settings say to go to localhost:

      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',

Comment: @AndrewAlexander is this error coming up from your Drupal installation or from some other script that you're writing?

Comment: I believe from Drupal - my other script seems to have no trouble accessing the MySQL database.

Comment: can you compare the two connection scripts and/or their parameters to be sure which one is throwing the error?